# R: how to properly create rx_forest_model object?

Tags: sql-server, r, microsoft-r

I'm trying to do a churn analysis with R and SQL Server 2016.
I have uploaded my dataset on my database in a local SQL Server and I did all the preliminary work on this dataset.
Well, now I have this function `trainModel()` which I would use to estimate my random model forest:

```
trainModel = function(sqlSettings, trainTable) {
sqlConnString = sqlSettings$connString

trainDataSQL <- RxSqlServerData(connectionString = sqlConnString,
                                table = trainTable,
                                colInfo = cdrColInfo)

## Create training formula
labelVar = "churn"
trainVars <- rxGetVarNames(trainDataSQL)
trainVars <- trainVars[!trainVars %in% c(labelVar)]
temp <- paste(c(labelVar, paste(trainVars, collapse = "+")), collapse = "~")
formula <- as.formula(temp)

## Train gradient tree boosting with mxFastTree on SQL data source
library(RevoScaleR)
rx_forest_model <- rxDForest(formula = formula,
                             data = trainDataSQL,
                             nTree = 8,
                             maxDepth = 16,
                             mTry = 2,
                             minBucket = 1,
                             replace = TRUE,
                             importance = TRUE,
                             seed = 8,
                             parms = list(loss = c(0, 4, 1, 0)))

return(rx_forest_model)
}
```

But when I run the function I get this wrong output:

```
> system.time({
+   trainModel(sqlSettings, trainTable)
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.29    0.07   58.18 
Warning message:
In tempGetNumObs(numObs) :
  Number of observations not available for this data source. 'numObs' set to 1e6.
```

And for this warning message, the function `trainModel()` does not create the object `rx_forest_model`

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts, I found the reason why the function `trainModel()` did not function properly.
Is not a connection string problem and is not even a data source type issue.
The problem is in the syntax of function `trainModel()`.

It is enough to eliminate from the body of the function the statement:

```
return(rx_forest_model)
```

In this way, the function returns the same warning message, but creates the object `rx_forest_model` in the correct way.

So, the correct function is:

```
trainModel = function(sqlSettings, trainTable) {
sqlConnString = sqlSettings$connString

trainDataSQL <- RxSqlServerData(connectionString = sqlConnString,
                            table = trainTable,
                            colInfo = cdrColInfo)

## Create training formula
labelVar = "churn"
trainVars <- rxGetVarNames(trainDataSQL)
trainVars <- trainVars[!trainVars %in% c(labelVar)]
temp <- paste(c(labelVar, paste(trainVars, collapse = "+")), collapse = "~")
formula <- as.formula(temp)

## Train gradient tree boosting with mxFastTree on SQL data source
library(RevoScaleR)
rx_forest_model <- rxDForest(formula = formula,
                             data = trainDataSQL,
                             nTree = 8,
                             maxDepth = 16,
                             mTry = 2,
                             minBucket = 1,
                             replace = TRUE,
                             importance = TRUE,
                             seed = 8,
                             parms = list(loss = c(0, 4, 1, 0)))

}
```

Comment: Your new function is basically identical to the old one. Did you remove the call to `system.time` when you ran it?

Comment: @HongOoi if you compare the two functions and if you read my reponse, you can see between thw two function.
I did not delete the statement
    system.time() 
I deleted return()

Comment: Deleting return doesn't do anything

Comment: deleting return(rx_forest_model) the function creates the object rx_forest_model.
If you put in the function return(rx_forest_model) the function works correctly, but does not create the object!

Comment: It doesn't _print_ the object. Hint: try assigning the result of your function to something.